# oscilloscope dead?

Tags: oscilloscope

I tried to calibrate the probes before i used the [DSO203](http://www.sainsmart.com/multimeter-usb-oscilloscope-meter-signal-generator-module/handheld-dso/sainsmart-arm-dso203-nano-4-channel-mini-v2-quad-pocket-digital-oscillo-scope.html). I hooked up the function generator to channels a and b (one at a time). I do not get a wave form shown on the screen with the settings adjusted to show a 10khz waveform. Is it dead?

Comment: Specific repair questions are off topic. Is there there an electronics question here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Signal source may be faulty.
Scope may be dead.
 Power may be off.
 Probe may be faulty.
 Probe may be grounded (some have a ground switch).
 Probe may be set to 10X with low signal
 Is there any display at all?

Scope may not be triggering (use in free run mode)
Level adjustment may be wrong (eg 100V setting with 1V signal.)

More information needed ...
I tried xxx so I know that yyy.
 Then I zzz so I know that ...

Answer (score 2):

That device is based on an STM32 microcontroller (though sampling is via a separate ADC), with I believe some options for customizing firmware.

So if it seems really unresponsive, I would look at attempting to talk to the micro, either in a data-download mode, or in a firmware upload mode, either via USB or via opening it an connecting to to SWD or UART (depending on the boot pin strappings).  In either of the latter cases you should be able to read out the id (STM32 varient) code, confirming the chip is not dead, irrespective of its current firmware or clock source availability.  You might need one of the $8 STM32 discovery modules as an STLINK SWD interface (try to get an STLINK-v2 version)